# Converting Oracle statement to SQL Server format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is an Oracle script that I need to execute on an SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
records.pr_id,
SUBSTR (REPLACE (REPLACE (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ("x", prad4.selection_value)
ORDER BY prad4.selection_value),'</x>'),'<x>',' ; '),4)  as teva_role
FROM records
```

Thanks for the help,

Barry

Comment: Please explain what you want the code to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed in SQL for years in several environments and it is about 75% the same. So, the SQL statement should work as is, however the functions (REPLACE, SUBSTR) will be what you need to research and change.

Also, you get columns from prad4 without including it in the FROM statement which is a problem.

And, finally, your parentheses aren't balanced which, I would think, would be a problem in Oracle as well.

Comment: I downvoted this, because it doesn't answer the question and should be a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically concatenating a set of strings with a delimiter. The common way to do this, is using `FOR XML PATH('')` which seems to be the equivalent of the combination of `XMLELEMENT()` in Oracle, but with a different syntax. You can also use XML functions to prevent change of certain characters not allowed in XML. The STUFF takes care of the `SUBSTR()` part of your code. For a more detailed explanation, you can read this article on [Creating a comma-separated list](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/creating-a-comma-separated-list-sql-spackle).

The code should look similar to this:

```
SELECT  records.pr_id,
        STUFF(( SELECT ' ; ' + prad4.selection_value
                FROM prad4
                WHERE prad4.pr_id = records.pr_id
                ORDER BY prad4.selection_value
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 3, '')
FROM records;
```

Of course, with the improvements of SQL Server 2017, the code can be simplified to something like this:

```
SELECT  records.pr_id,
        STRING_AGG( selection_value, ' ; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY selection_value ASC) 
FROM records;
```